# How to feed Slack archive into GSA?

Tags: google-search-appliance, slack-api

I am wondering how can I use Slack API to feed message history into GSA (Google Search Appliance) and having this kept up to date.

Did anyone wrote a script for this?

Comment: Do you know the new connector mechanism of the GSA ? It uses the crawler to "crawl" a dynamic index page created by the connector. Depending on what the slack api offers you might have a simple REST call create such a index page which the GSA is then able to crawl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a readymade script, but it should be possible as you've imagined; IMO (without being familiar with the slack api, but with some knowledge of the slack archive sizes, i.e., >500K messages), I think the main challenge would be to identify and extract only the pieces of information that are important to you from the slack archive (which can easily get you to run out of your GSA document index license limit if you chose your GSA feed record elements too discretely - e.g., imagine if every message were a separate feed record).

In other words, you need to identify the discrete feed records keeping them as atomically large as possible in order to keep the document license usage down to a minimum, while keeping them discrete enough to yield accurate results.

Once that's done, or if your GSA index license limit is not a problem, one possible solution is to create an incremental/full feed by reading updates from the slack archive using its API, and then compiling the new records found, into the GSA feed format (with information that you want to be able to search-on/omit contained within the  tags as appropriate, and info that you need to present in the results, contained in html meta tags), and push those new records in to the GSA.

Another solution, if you'd be able to host a few web application pages that you can have the GSA crawl, will even allow you to keep its index up to date with a continuous crawl. For this you'd need at least one "jump page" which would just be a list of links each populated with query string parameters, to be passed to your detail record page, which would serve to identify a set of various slack message archive element IDs, that you've determined as needing to be indexed as a discrete record. You'd then need to set your "jump page" URL to be crawled by the GSA, and also develop your XSLT or other search results consumer service to be able to read/render the returned results with info contained in meta tags. Note: when the consumer service makes the search call to GSA, it'll need to pass in a "&getfields=*" query string parameter to get the GSA to return all the info contained in the meta tags.

I hope that my wording is not too esoteric and helps you in some way in designing your solution.